# How to add command arguments to main? Java

Tags: java, command-line-arguments

How can I setup my main to accept command switches?

a source port `(-s source_port)` and the destination hostname `(-h hostname)` and port `(-p port)` of the receiving application as well as the audit log file `(-l log_file)`. One IDS misuse keyword `(–m misuse_keyword)` and a misuse threshold `(-t misuse_threshold)` are also specified on the command line.

Basically, I want to have -h localhost set a field named hostname = localhost and -l bob.txt set to a field named `inputfile = "bob.txt"`. How do I do this in Java? I can do this in C and C++ but not sure how to do this in Java.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

}
```

Comment: Those will be passed into the `args` array. `java Test arguments here` would execute a class `Test` with a main method, with `String[]{"arguments", "here"}` as program arguments.

Comment: Have you tried anything? With what part of the code are you struggling? Do you know how Java arrays work? The concepts here aren't really different from those in C/C++.

Comment: are u going to give input manually? .txt file or something else...

Comment: There are libraries to parse command line parameters (Commons CLI, for instance). Do not reinvent the wheel.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do something like this in your `main()` method

```
  args = new String[12];
    args[0]="-s";
    args[1]="source_port";// something integer value "1324"
    args[2]="-h";
    args[3]="hostname";
    args[4]="-p";
    args[5]="port";
    args[6]="-l";
    args[7]="log_file";
    args[8]="-m";
    args[9]="misuse_keyword";
    args[10]="-t";
    args[11]="misuse_threshold";
```

while storing in another variable

```
int source_port = Integer.parseInt(args[1]);
```

Comment: so source_port is a variable in my code so would i still need it in ""

Comment: @user977154 store it in `""` and while initializing to another variable pare it in Integer value.

Answer (score 4):

In java if you pass `-h hostname -p port` you will receive array with 4 elements `{"-h", "hostname", "-p", "port"}`. So you will have to manage the keys parsing manually.

Here is an example:

```
private static final String HOST_KEY = "-h";
private static final String PORT_KEY = "-p";

public static void main(String[] args)
{
    String host = "";
    String port = "";

    for(int i=0; i<args.length; i+=2)
    {
        String key = args[i];
        String value = args[i+1];

        switch (key)
        {
            case HOST_KEY : host = value; break;
            case PORT_KEY : port = value; break;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: where do i put this in my main?

Comment: these params will be contained in `args` array

Comment: i am really sorry. This should be very simple. Do you think you can show me exactly what my main should look like

Comment: @user977154 here it is

Comment: I did the other way using a map

Comment: Try using Apache Commons CLI to handle the parsing and validation.

Answer (score 1):

Just put the argument after your program name. For example

```
java addProgram 1 2
```

In your case, it should be

```
java YourProgramName "-s source_port_value" "-h hostname_value" "-p port_value"
```

These values will be received by main method in args (String array), then you can iterate the array and get the flag options and their corresponding values to proceed with your operation. I have put the double quotes to make them as a single input value. we have three arguments passing into the main method

Logic to parse the value

```
public static void main(String[] args){

HashMap<String,String> properties = new HashMap<String,String>();

for(int i=0;i<args.length;i++){

if(args[i].trim().startsWith("-s"))
properties.put("source_port",args[i].split(" ")[1]);
if(args[i].trim().startsWith("-h"))
properties.put("hostname",args[i].split(" ")[1]);
if(args[i].trim().startsWith("-p"))
properties.put("port",args[i].split(" ")[1]);

}
//this will give you all the property values mapped with their keys after this looping
//you can get the values from properties map from here onwards
}
```

Comment: isnt this how i run it? I am trying to parse the command argument to fields in my source code

Comment: Hi, is it possible to put the HashMap code in a separate class and pass the args to that class?